# Apache Flume custom sink data conflict

Tags: java, json, thread-safety, flume-ng

I am trying to create single source multiple sink flume-ng dataflow. We have custom udp source, file_roll sink, custom rabbitmqjson sink.

in custom Rabbitmqjson sink process:

```
        Event event = getChannel().take();
        if(event==null){
            tx.rollback();
            return Status.BACKOFF;
        }
        Map<String, String> eventMap = getMap(event);
        event.setBody(toJson(eventMap).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

changing event body to json with headers and its working fine.RabbitMQ gets all data as json.However, sometimes file_roll sink stores data as json too.

How custom sink events goes to non-custom sink with different channels when dataflow is fast? maybe java thread issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by json too? you mean bytes as will as json?

Comment: here's the thing, we want RabbitMQ data like {"eventHeader":"header","eventBody":"body"} and 
File_Roll data = body, 

however file_roll stores data like
{"eventHeader":"header1","eventBody":"body1"}
body2
body3
{"eventHeader":"header3","eventBody":"body3"}

Comment: some of events conflict with each other